# Prevent user from turning off mobile data and location

Tags: android, internet-connection, location-services

What I want to do is is there a very way to prevent user from turning off Mobile Data & Location services?

My scenario is this, I am creating a mobile application for a big project we have now. This application is restricted for the use of their employees going out of the field, now this phone by any means should not turn off mobile data and location services as I have an application service that sends constant location data to the administration API.

OR maybe an existing application that prevent native functions like this from being accessed. This may sound crazy but I just have thought if there is something like this.

Thank you!
I hope someone could enlighten me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

Even if you could, it would not solve anything, because there are many other reasons why those services may not work. For example when one is driving through a tunnel and there is no signal or out of town there may sometimes be no signal or the network may be overloaded or something. So you can't rely on these services anyway. Intermittent loss of connectivity is pretty common in mobile devices. You will have to take it into account (log data and send them when you succeed in reconnecting).

If the users need the application, and connectivity in it, to do their job, they won't be turning it off, because they need it. So all that is needed is to create a notification when connectivity and/or location is lost so the user can do something about it if:

- the application fails to connect when they turn it on at the start of their shift or
- the application looses connection for extended period of time for whatever reason.

And of course if there is somebody in the company using the data (some dispatcher), which I suppose there is, they will notice the particular worker is not sending anything and will try to contact them by calling or something. These should take care of mistakes and faults.

If the users don't need it and it is intended to spy on them (so they may have a reason to disable it), it is probably illegal anyway.

Comment: Thank you, though this feature is optional anyways. Your suggestion are a pretty good work around =D

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prevent user from turning off Mobile data. But you can simple record location in a file with time while data is off and send it immediately after user turn on the data.

Answer (score 2):

That is impossible unless the device is rooted.

And it makes perfect sense, because that would compromise the user's experience of Android and/or security.

You must anticipate circumstances like the user turning off the data or connection and act appropriately (for example gracefully stall your connections with the internet and resume them later, inform the user that his device has been disconnected from the internet and that your application requires internet access etc...).